# React typescript pass array of name in the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I writing the React Typescript components to take the array of `Props` value. but the below code giving me the error in the `map` statement.

> Property 'map' does not exist on type
> 'Readonly'.ts(2339)

**Code**

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface IListNameProps {
    names: string[]
}

export interface IListNameState {

}

export default class ListName extends React.Component<IListNameProps, IListNameState> {

  constructor(props: IListNameProps) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
    }
  }

  public render() {
    return (
        <ul>
          {this.props.map((name) => (
            <li key={name}>{name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
  }
}
```

What is the correct way of passing array of string to React components?

Thanks

Comment: Didn't you mean to iterate over `this.props.names`?

Comment: Yes, want to loop thru and print the names

Comment: `this.props.names.map((name)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over `names` which you passed as props
Also I don't see benefit of using class component its confusing, here I updated the syntax. But if you prefer to use class then just update the `this.props.map` to `this.props.names.map`

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export interface IListNameProps {
  names: string[]
}


export default function ListNames(props: IListNameProps) {
  return (
    <ul>
    {props.names.map((name) => (
      <li key={name}>{name}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
  );
}
```